# Missing Groups After Syncing with iCloud

Tags: icloud

I lost all of my groups when syncing Outlook 2010 with iCloud sync on Windows.

How do I get them back?

Comment: This question is probably going to need more detail for someone to answer it. Are you syncing on a device? A computer? What version of iOS or OSX are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you do backups [look for the .pst-file](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/03656301-a36c-413e-885e-0811bf9cc58b/where-is-the-default-location-for-pst-files-in-office-2010-in-windows-xp-what-about-windows-7?forum=outlook) (office identity) and restore it from a backup.